# .net asp.net web app trying to connect to crl.verisign.net

Tags: asp.net, ssl

I have a web service that is consuming a third party webservice over https over a dedicated connection, I applied the ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback mechanism to overpass the ssl, the service is working, but the problem is that everytime I invoke the third party webservice there is a connection trying to get to crl.verisign.net, the problem is that our production servers don't have internet connection, and because of this is delaying 9 secs per call.

Is there any way to get rid of this connection to  crl.verisign.net? any help would be appreciate it.

Thanks

ServerCertificateValidationCallback code:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = New RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AddressOf SubCertHandler)
ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = False

Private Shared Function SubCertHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal certificate As X509Certificate, ByVal chain As X509Chain, ByVal sslPolicyErrors As SslPolicyErrors) As Boolean
    Return True
End Function
```

Comment: Simple answer: change hosts file to point to localhost

Comment: Can we see the code you are using for the callback validation?

Comment: The code I'm using is this: code ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = New RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AddressOf SubCertHandler) ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = False Private Shared Function SubCertHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal certificate As X509Certificate, ByVal chain As X509Chain, ByVal sslPolicyErrors As SslPolicyErrors) As Boolean Return True End Function `code`

Answer (score 3):

This is a common problem.   The solution is sometimes environment specific.

If you are already using ServicePointManager, try setting the CheckCertificationRevocationList property to false.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.checkcertificaterevocationlist.aspx

Comment: Already tried the CheckCertificationRevocationList and didn't work. 

The code I'm using is this:

`code`
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = New RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AddressOf SubCertHandler)
        ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = False


Private Shared Function SubCertHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal certificate As X509Certificate, ByVal chain As X509Chain, ByVal sslPolicyErrors As SslPolicyErrors) As Boolean
        Return True
    End Function

`code`

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. In the server there's a service called "Win http Web Proxy Auto Discovery", when we disabled this service everything worked as expected.

Thanks for your help!!!